# InnoSetup - copy files before install

Tags: inno-setup

How can we copy, move, rename user files before installation?

We can easily delete files using the [InstallDelete] section:

```
[InstallDelete]
Type: files; Name: "{app}\SomeFile.exe";
```

Can we do copy, rename in a similar way?

EDIT:

I tried to make this in [Files] section but I receive an error during compilation because source file does not exist:

```
[Files]
Source: "{app}\SomeFile.exe"; DestDir: "{app}\SomeDir\SomeFile.exe";
```

Comment: If the source file doesn't exist, how is InnoSetup supposed to include it in the installation?

Comment: @Thorsten, you can use [`external`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection&anchor=external) flag, but it's a bad idea even if it would work.

Comment: @Thorsten: I do not want to include these file in installation. These  are user]s save files that I want to move in other subdirectory of the application (if files exists).

Comment: Yes, that's what I was talking about :-) The way you were trying it, the compiler expects the files to be present on your local harddrive to include them in the setup.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For copying files you can use the `[Files]` section, but I don't think there's a way for move or rename operations in a separate section, so I would suggest you to use `[Code]` section for this.

Here is a sample code for move and rename operations. They both use the [`RenameFile`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_renamefile) function as it is internally the same operation:

```
[Code]
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if CurStep = ssInstall then
  begin
    // move file
    if not RenameFile(ExpandConstant('{app}\SomeDir\SomeFile.exe'), ExpandConstant('{app}\SomeFile.exe')) then
      MsgBox('File moving failed!', mbError, MB_OK);
    // rename file
    if not RenameFile(ExpandConstant('{app}\SomeFile.exe'), ExpandConstant('{app}\RenamedSomeFile.exe')) then
      MsgBox('File moving failed!', mbError, MB_OK);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you! I was just looking what [Code] function to use to place the move code. procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep); will work fine. Even better, I can warn the user that I have moved his save files.

Comment: Bear in mind that user files should be in one of the `{user*}` folders -- and that you can't rely on the installer to move these for you.  The installer is only run by one user, but multiple may have been using your application.  It has to be the responsibility of the application itself to manage these.