# How to create a setup in C# without adding external files?

Tags: xml, embed, exe

I have one XML file. I want to attach that file with EXE, but I don't want to embed it in the EXE.
That XML will be with EXE.
So EXE will execute at that time it will read that external XML data.

How we can achieve that?

Comment: you want to create an application bundle?

Comment: See I have setup created with SQLExpress framwork Prerequisites.Now I want to add one external file which will also get copied to Installed folder but dont want that to embed it in EXE. Because user can change content of that file and then those changes can be available after installation.

Comment: When I will install the exe i need to copy that XML file into installed folder. without embedding it in Setup.exe

Comment: That can be done. Refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16586279/innosetup-copy-files-before-install

Comment: No Its embedding the files in EXE.I dont want to do that.I just want to attach external file with it.As any user can change the xml and run the setup.

Comment: any Idea how we can implement it?

Comment: The XMl file will be copied to any location that you want whilst the installation is going on. Is that not what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Use setup builders like Inno Setup(http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) or you can use a self extracting WinRAR archive.

Comment: I tried with self extracting WinRAR but its also not working as I want. any different Solution

Comment: with rar you can place the setup file and xml in one rar bundle and then distribute it. This way the xml wont be inside the setup file.